# IOKit driver for generic graphics tablet pen?

Tags: macos, driver, hid, iokit, kernel-extension

I brought a Genius G-Pen 340 tablet pen years ago. After upgrading to Mavericks, I found that the original driver to the tablet pen would not be loaded. It seems that the driver was for 32-bit OS X only, and apparently this product has been out of support for a while.

Is it possible to build a kext, to let IOHIDFamily driver work with this tablet pen? Or has any project tried to support more HID input devices than the IOHIDSystem kext?

It seems that the IOHIDFamily has built-in support for Digitizer device class, but lacks the product specific configurations. I also briefly greped the Linux kernel source code, and tested on a Linux laptop and found that this tablet pen is recognised as WP4030U and works well. It seems that many tablet pen products are supported by supplying various configuration parameters to the same driver.

The Linux kernel driver that supplies parameters for the tablet pen:

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/164c09978cebebd8b5fc198e9243777dbaecdfa0/drivers/hid/hid-uclogic.c

The `ioreg` result for the tablet:

```
| |   |   +-o Tablet WP4030U@24110000  <class IOUSBDevice, id 0x100000755, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (415 ms), retain 10>
| |   |     +-o IOUSBCompositeDriver  <class IOUSBCompositeDriver, id 0x100000759, !registered, !matched, active, busy 0, retain 4>
| |   |     +-o Tablet WP4030U@0  <class IOUSBInterface, id 0x10000075a, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (43 ms), retain 9>
| |   |       +-o IOUSBHIDDriver  <class IOUSBHIDDriver, id 0x100000762, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (6 ms), retain 10>
| |   |         +-o IOHIDInterface  <class IOHIDInterface, id 0x100000765, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (5 ms), retain 7>
| |   |         | +-o IOHIDEventDriver  <class IOHIDEventDriver, id 0x100000767, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (0 ms), retain 9>
| |   |         |   +-o IOHIDPointing  <class IOHIDPointing, id 0x100000768, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (0 ms), retain 8>
| |   |         |   | +-o IOHIDSystem  <class IOHIDSystem, id 0x10000024a, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (0 ms), retain 23>
| |   |         |   |   +-o IOHIDStackShotUserClient  <class IOHIDStackShotUserClient, id 0x100000324, !registered, !matched, active, busy 0, retain 5>
| |   |         |   |   +-o IOHIDUserClient  <class IOHIDUserClient, id 0x10000034c, !registered, !matched, active, busy 0, retain 5>
| |   |         |   |   +-o IOHIDParamUserClient  <class IOHIDParamUserClient, id 0x10000034d, !registered, !matched, active, busy 0, retain 5>
| |   |         |   |   +-o IOHIDEventSystemUserClient  <class IOHIDEventSystemUserClient, id 0x100000363, !registered, !matched, active, busy 0, retain 5>
| |   |         |   |   +-o IOHIDEventSystemUserClient  <class IOHIDEventSystemUserClient, id 0x100000364, !registered, !matched, active, busy 0, retain 5>
| |   |         |   |   +-o IOHIDEventSystemUserClient  <class IOHIDEventSystemUserClient, id 0x10000036a, !registered, !matched, active, busy 0, retain 5>
| |   |         |   +-o IOHIDSystem  <class IOHIDSystem, id 0x10000024a, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (0 ms), retain 22>
| |   |         |     +-o IOHIDStackShotUserClient  <class IOHIDStackShotUserClient, id 0x100000324, !registered, !matched, active, busy 0, retain 5>
| |   |         |     +-o IOHIDUserClient  <class IOHIDUserClient, id 0x10000034c, !registered, !matched, active, busy 0, retain 5>
| |   |         |     +-o IOHIDParamUserClient  <class IOHIDParamUserClient, id 0x10000034d, !registered, !matched, active, busy 0, retain 5>
| |   |         |     +-o IOHIDEventSystemUserClient  <class IOHIDEventSystemUserClient, id 0x100000363, !registered, !matched, active, busy 0, retain 5>
| |   |         |     +-o IOHIDEventSystemUserClient  <class IOHIDEventSystemUserClient, id 0x100000364, !registered, !matched, active, busy 0, retain 5>
| |   |         |     +-o IOHIDEventSystemUserClient  <class IOHIDEventSystemUserClient, id 0x10000036a, !registered, !matched, active, busy 0, retain 5>
| |   |         +-o IOHIDLibUserClient  <class IOHIDLibUserClient, id 0x100000766, !registered, !matched, active, busy 0, retain 6>
| |   |         +-o IOHIDLibUserClient  <class IOHIDLibUserClient, id 0x10000076a, !registered, !matched, active, busy 0, retain 6>
```

Comment: I should have some time to research and try some things related to this in about 3-4 weeks' time. I'll answer then if I can. Of course, anyone who knows how to do this answers before then, even better. :-)

Comment: It is not very important now. I have found a driver for Mavericks from UC-Logic instead of Genius.